# Connotation of "lead to"

Tags: word-meaning

I know "Lead" means "Cause something to happen"

> the events that led to the start of World War 1.

But I suspect it is used for bad happenings! is it right? if yes, what is the word to use for good happenings?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I don't think that **lead** is always used for talking about unfavorable results; consider this:

> ... *and Fifteenth Amendments; these rights would lead to progress in political equality; political equality would lead to social equality; and social equality would lead to intermarriage between whites and blacks and ..* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=yJVz2gcLl-oC&pg=PA102&dq=%22would%20lead%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR77K76ejOAhWPbZoKHWMQDrY4UBDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=%22would%20lead%20to%22&f=false))

However, I agree that there are considerable number of sentences in which that verb has been used to describe a bad occurrence.

Secondly, if you want a verb that can be used for good happenings, I suggest that you can use the verb **[pay off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pay-off)**:

> *All those weeks of studying will pay off when you take the exam*

I can also suggest the verb [**bring about**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bring-about):

> *Thus, the love of good things, which is common to all people, brings about happiness*. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=TTtLRPVAvtEC&pg=PA15&dq=%22brings%20about%20happiness%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1ipTD6-jOAhVqAZoKHUSGCL0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22brings%20about%20happiness%22&f=false))

---

Added information:

I forgot to mention that, I regularly see in technical papers that the verb **[result in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/result-in)** is used, especially when someone wants to discuss about what happens after they change some parameters:

> *Changing the wire diameter a certain percentage at unaltered resistance **results in** a bigger wire surface load and temperature change for a wire that has a large temperature factor than for a wire with a small factor.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKpfn0OpXEsC&pg=PA39&dq=%22results%20in%20a%20bigger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUhJLr7ejOAhUFVywKHYz6D2oQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22results%20in%20a%20bigger%22&f=false))

Answer (score 2):

"Lead/Led to" can be used for either without sounding weird.

"His poor behaviour in school led to him being expelled" is negative, whereas

"The hard work he put in led to him getting a promotion" is positive.